# Chomsky languages: how to recognize them?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar, context-sensitive-grammar, chomsky-hierarchy

I have a problem with the recognition of languages. Given a certain language, for example <kbd>a<sup>n</sup>cb<sup>2n</sup>, n > 0</kbd>, how do I determine quickly what type belongs according Chomsky?

My idea was to determine the grammar that generates it and then up to the language but it is a long process. I think there's another way to recognize it by eye,
without writing grammars or automata.
can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, associating an arbitrary language with a level of the Chomsky hierarchy is, in the general case, undecidable. (See [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).)

Of course, it is easy to categorize a given grammar, since the Chomsky hierarchy is defined by a simple syntactic analysis of the grammar itself. However, languages do not have unique grammars; the existence of (for example) a Type 2 (context-free) grammar for a language does not mean that there is not a Type 3 (regular) grammar for the same language.

So there are no shortcuts.

However, there is a lot to be said for experience. The language `{ ancb2n | n > 0 }` is context-free (and not regular), as are all languages of similar forms. That it is context free is demonstrated by the grammar

```
L → c
L → a L b b
```

and the fact that it is not regular can be proven using the [pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). (The linked Wikipedia article contains, as an example of the use of the lemma, a proof for a similar language which should be easy to adapt.)

On the other hand, a language which requires three equal counts (`{ ancnbn | n > 0 }`) is not context-free (but is context-sensitive). (That's not the same as `{ ancn+mbm | n > 0 }`, which *is* context-free.)